# how to check if the file upload field null then save data without file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to save products with product image but some times i dont have product image and i need to save the products without image name but when i didnt select image and try to save i got the error object reference not set to an instance of an object ,
This is the create action code :

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file,[Bind(Include = "order_id,hospital_id,department_id,employee_id,status_id,order_details,user_id,order_date,update_date,deleted_date,file")] hospital_orders hospital_orders)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                hospital_orders.file = file.FileName;
                db.hospital_orders.Add(hospital_orders);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // uploaf file

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    
                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/upload/" + file.FileName));
                }
                
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(hospital_orders);
        }
```

I need to check if fileName empty then save without file :

```
hospital_orders.file = file.FileName;
```

How to do that ?

Comment: You may check this adding a breakpoint to `hospital_orders.file = file.FileName;` line. What is the `file` value when you do not send any image. And after you saw the value you can take action according to this value. Like `if (file != null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you pass filename to the model if the HttpPostedFileBase contains null(ie: no file selected).
Before this line "hospital_orders.file = file.FileName;" check your null condition.
Do like this.

```
if(file !=null)
    hospital_orders.file = file.FileName;
  db.hospital_orders.Add(hospital_orders);
  db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thank you its working but you should add else condition if file = null

Comment: Welcome! But I think there is no need for an extra block for else condition.